# Change the set to a separate list in python

Tags: python

```
a= [{'w', 'r', 't', 'y', 'e'}, {'f', 'g', 'w', 's', 'd'}]
```

How to change this data set into a separate list so that

```
b = ['w', 'r', 't', 'y', 'e']
c = ['f', 'g', 'w', 's', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
assert len(a) == 2
b, c = [list(s) for s in a]
```